# Export int from PHPMyadmin as json

Tags: php, mysql, json, phpmyadmin

I am trying to export a simple database table as json with 2 fields:

**id(int)
name(varchar)**

When I do so I get this:

```
[{"id":"1","name":"Mike"}, {"id":"2","name":"Peter"}]
```

my issue here is that the id fields should be without the "" around the number?!? How do I accomplish this?

Hoping for help and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Is your `id` field integer? I just dumped my data and it's working as you described

Comment: How are you creating JSON from `phpMyAdmin`? Do you mean a PHP script? Show the code.

Comment: @Barmar phpMyAdmin -> some table view -> export -> JSON from the DropDown

Comment: Sounds like a limitation of phpMyAdmin, it doesn't preserve the column types. Why is this a problem? Most scripting languages will automatically convert strings to numbers when necessary.

Comment: It is exported from PHPMyadmin as json! The reason this is an issue is that I want to use the json to import into an class on Parse.com. This can only be done with json and if the predifined field in parse.com is number it wont accept an string!?

Comment: Is there any issue with this? I think for security purpose it has been limited to this.

Comment: I want the int fields to be numbers in Parse.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have old version of `phpmyadmin` that might be the case here. I have used `phpmyadmin version : 3.5.2` and it worked efficiently and it has exported this data:

```
[{
    "id": 1, // <--------------------no quotes when exported
    "username": "jai****hsah",
    "password": "jai@***",
    "email": "******@gmail.com"
},
{
    "id": 2, //<---------------------no quotes when exported
    "username": "ash***05",
    "password": "*****@2005",
    "email": "a******@gmail.com"
}]
```

---

My version of **phpMyAdmin** is **3.5.2** Although **4.2.2** is available. You can update to this and check if this solves the issue.

Comment: If this does not fix your issue, you should post your `create table` definition. Maybe your column in the table is not even an integer one.